# Python - repeating the same loop index if an condition occurs

Tags: python

I have a python script that will pull data for some stock tickers (yfinance) and then create ticker specific datasets for additional use. Basically, I grap a list with all the symbols I'm interested in and then run a for each in... loop. Occationally I find that one or more of the database files is empty when the analysis stage is performed.

It's not too bad to just notice that an "empty dataframe" condition when the process its that and then go back and pull that data again. BUT...doesn't seem like how a real programmer would actually deal with it.

Unfortunately I'm hardly a real programmer so the only thing I can really think about doing would be before writing the file to check to see if there actually was data (other than the header info) and if not put that ticker in an error list and set a code indicating a post job need to be done. Then I can pass the list of tickers that produce empty files, repull the data and done (or perhaps wash and repeat or something).

But then I started thinking. The slick way to do this might be to catch the condition and then just have the exiting look just use the same symbol for pulling the data and making the dataset. In other worlds, don'tupdate the loop index somehow for the next loop. In other words, if the download for XOM failed so the dataframe.to_csv() writes an empty file I would like to catch that the download and repeat the download for XOM again.

Does python have something like that?

Have not tried the solution I could think of. It's not too much trouble to manually intervene. Might be more work to change the program than manually addressing the rare cases. But if there was a simply method in python that would accomplish repeating the loop and then condinuing

Here is what is I'm currently doing:

```
for sym in trade_sym:
    o_file = wdir + sym + ".csv"
    try:
        print(f'Getting {sym} data . . .')
        p_data= yf.download(sym, auto_adjust = True)
        print(f'Processing {sym} data . . .')

. . . [manipluate the data and create the dataframe to write]


    except:
        print(f'{sym}\t{error}')
        continue

. . .
```

I don't think I can put repeat in rather than continue but have not tried. I'm not finding anything online that suggests I can do that (but often search poorly).

Answer (score 1):

Use a nested loop that retries a number of times.

```
retry_limit = 5

for sym in trade_sym:
    for _ in range(retry_limit):
        try:
            print(f'Getting {sym} data . . .')
            p_data= yf.download(sym, auto_adjust = True)
            print(f'Processing {sym} data . . .')
            # manipulate the data
            break
        except Exception as error:
            print(f'{sym}\t{error}')
    else:
        print(f'{sym}\tretry limit reached')
```

Comment: Thanks that seems like a solution I could add pretty easily -- appreciate the suggestion.